# Call This Function Outside of Form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a submit button at the end of my form that is labeled like this:

```
<button id="sendbutton" style="margin-left:25px;" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Send Responses</button>
```

This button calls this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('form').unbind('submit').bind('submit', function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'chapter.php',
                    data: $("form").serialize(),
                    success: function() {
                        alert('Your answers have been saved.');
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });

    </script>
```

How do I create a button outside of this form structure that will call the same function?

Comment: Basicaly you want to submit the form on click of that button that is outside the form as well right?

Comment: Why are you doing `.unbind('submit')`? Is there really other code that may have registered a submit handler on your form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create whatever button you'd like, even if its outside of the form.  And then, to get that button to do the same thing you could simply do

```
$('#yourNewButton').click(function(){
    $('form').submit();
});
```

Or, why not wrap up your original logic into its own function

```
function submitMyForm(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'chapter.php',
        data: $("form").serialize(),
        success: function() {
            alert('Your answers have been saved.');
        }
    });
    return false;
 }
```

And then

```
$('#yourNewButton').click(submitMyForm);
$('form').submit(submitMyForm);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a click handler to the new button and in the handler trigger the form submit using script

```
<button id="test" style="margin-left:25px;" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Send Responses</button>
```

then

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#test').click(function(){
        $('form').submit()
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than make the submit handler an anonymous function you make it a named function

```
function submitHandler() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'chapter.php',
        data: $("form").serialize(),
        success: function () {
            alert('Your answers have been saved.');
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

then change your code to

```
$('form').unbind('submit').bind('submit', submitHandler);
```

That way you can call that function whenever you like simple by writing `submitHandler();`